# Google Play In-App Subscription Items - Toggle Active and Inactive in Developer Console

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, in-app-subscription

What are the implications for changing an In-App Subscription item from Active to Inactive?

1. Can this item be re-activated later without complications?
2. When changing the item from Active to Inactive does this affect any
   users who are currently subscribed to said item?  More specifically,
   does changing an item from Active to Inactive cancel any currently
   "active" subscriptions that a user may have purchase?

My assumptions for each question are "yes" and "no" respectively, but I'd like some clarity on this before "pulling the trigger" and can't find any specific documentation that pertains to either question.

Comment: Over three years and I still can't find proper documentation about what _active_ and _inactive_ does...

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I can tell that Inactive item for subscription is valid only for alpha and beta testing. These items won't be visible for app version which is in production.

After you change state to "Active" you won't be able to change prices for that item. As currencies exchange changes in different countries you will need to provide new SKU(items) for subscriptions and update them respectively, because google doesn't do it on automatic basis comparing to apple.

I just checked, and result as follows:
Trying to buy Inactive product (Error, this product is not selling)
[image]

Buying Product that was Activated( Product purchase detail information, 7 days trial)
[image]

Comment: Any documentation about the Inactive state? I've installed a signed app to my test device and I'm still getting inactive products!

Answer (score 0):

An in-app subscription cannot be deactivated once it's activated, so these are moot questions.

In the Play Console I have this message on an active subscription:

> An active subscription can't be deactivated at any time

Comment: I believe that, when I asked this question, there was no indication in the play store console that subscriptions cannot be deactivated.  Thank you for following up!